# Auto pay with vault Paypal

Tags: asp.net-web-api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to auto pay with paypal saved vault card.i am using paypal sdk(.Net Framework).
when i call default method for payment it reflect error "payer_id is required for payments made with this token."

and after that i pass paypal merchant account id in "payer_id".
give error "payer_id does not match token ID."

what is concept of payer_id ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution, When save vault for paypal account in that i was choose also pass payer_id for this. so during the auto payment it required payer_id.

Also when we use sandbox payment from saved vault it reflect "500 internal server error." it is due to save dummy data in vault.(eg. cvv number).